# Graph RAGs , LLMs and building connectivity sub-graph

Tags: graph, neo4j, langchain, large-language-model, retrieval-augmented

We are considering building knowlede-graph based Data Catalog solution to register meta-data of data-sources,tables (and other data assets) in our systems. Our goal is to build a Graph based RAG (Retrieval-Augmented Generation) on top of this knowledge-graph.

Ultimate goal is to provide an interface for data consumer to get comprehensive answers for the data-source/sets related queries.

For the POC, I came up with  following simplified meta-data model :
[image]

Then I modeled a knowledge-graph using Neo4J for the following sample table model:
[image]

Resulting graph look like this:
[image]

Vector-index is also created for the nodes.

Now I want to build a Graph based RAG, which can refer this knowledge-graph and provide comprehensive answer to the users.Queries can be like:

**"How can I find the top 5 shipping methods by user count"**

For this query we can get the vector embedding and do a vector-search against the graph.This will  probably give "shipping" table and "user" table info from the graph-db.

But to construct the correct answer, we need to provide the complete relationship between *user*,*order* and *shipment* tables to the LLM.That is, depend on the query, we need to transverse the graph and build the connectivity sub-graph between tables/columns.

My questions are:

1. How can I build this connectivity sub-graph depend on the query?
2. Can I use [ReAct](https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.03629) (Reason and Action) based template to instruct LLM to use an Agent to query till it can find relationships ?
3. Does frameworks like LangChain or LLamaIndex provide this kind of functionality?